# radiobuttons and conditional checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, radio-button

I have 2 radio-buttons and a checkbox.

When the first option is "personalized" the checkbox "hidden" should be automatically checked.

[image: buttons and checkbox]

```
<div class="field-type-list-text field-name-field-main-download-category field-widget-options-buttons form-wrapper" id="edit-field-main-download-category"><div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-field-main-download-category-und">
      <label for="edit-field-main-download-category-und">Main Download Category </label>
     <div id="edit-field-main-download-category-und" class="form-radios"><div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-main-download-category-und">
     <input type="radio" id="edit-field-main-download-category-und-general" name="field_main_download_category[und]" value="general" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-field-main-download-category-und-general">General </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-main-download-category-und">
     <input type="radio" id="edit-field-main-download-category-und-personalized" name="field_main_download_category[und]" value="personalized" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-field-main-download-category-und-personalized">Personalized </label>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div><div class="field-type-list-boolean field-name-field-hidden field-widget-options-onoff form-wrapper" id="edit-field-hidden"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-hidden-und">
     <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-hidden-und" name="field_hidden[und]" value="1" class="form-checkbox" />  <label class="option" for="edit-field-hidden-und">Hidden </label>

    </div></div>
```

I've made this script, but it is not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if ( $('.personalized input').val() = "personalized" ) {
    $('.checkbox input').attr('checked');
  }
});
```

Comment: You should provide your HTML.

Comment: I provided an answer based on your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few problems. As others already pointed out, you are checking `document.ready` instead of `onChange` event. So it checks on page load, instead of checking on radio button state change.
Another problem is that you are checking `$('.personalized input')` value, but you do not have `personalized` class in your html.
Your radio buttons have common class `form-radio`. So you can use it as a selector.

```js
$('.form-radio').on("change", function(){
  if ( $(this).val() == "personalized" ) {
    $('.form-checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  }
  else{
    $('.form-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-type-list-text field-name-field-main-download-category field-widget-options-buttons form-wrapper" id="edit-field-main-download-category"><div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-field-main-download-category-und">
      <label for="edit-field-main-download-category-und">Main Download Category </label>
     <div id="edit-field-main-download-category-und" class="form-radios"><div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-main-download-category-und">
     <input type="radio" id="edit-field-main-download-category-und-general" name="field_main_download_category[und]" value="general" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-field-main-download-category-und-general">General </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-main-download-category-und">
     <input type="radio" id="edit-field-main-download-category-und-personalized" name="field_main_download_category[und]" value="personalized" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-field-main-download-category-und-personalized">Personalized </label>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div><div class="field-type-list-boolean field-name-field-hidden field-widget-options-onoff form-wrapper" id="edit-field-hidden"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-hidden-und">
     <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-hidden-und" name="field_hidden[und]" value="1" class="form-checkbox" />  <label class="option" for="edit-field-hidden-und">Hidden </label>

    </div></div>
```

This part:

```
else{
    $('.form-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
```

you only need if you want to un-check if not personalized. 
Also take care of `.prop()` which is used for jQuery 1.6+. For lower  versions use `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify when do you want the script to check if the `radio` is checked or not. If you use just `document.ready()` function, it will check it only **once**, when the site is loaded and since it's not checked - the checkbox won't be checked neither.

You can use following approach: check it with every click event on the `radio` button.

```js
$('.personalized').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' class='personalized'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here:

- The code as written only runs on page load. Since you said you want the checkbox to be "automatically" checked, you should attach a change handler to the radio array.
- `.val()` called on a radio array returns the value of the first element in the selected set, regardless of which one is checked. You need to add `:checked` to your selector to filter down to the one selected radio element.
- Your single equals sign is the assignment operator and should be replaced with `===`.
- `.attr('checked')` returns the value of the `checked` attribute. There are actually two problems here: `attr` only looks at the attribute initially assigned to the element; you need to use `prop` instead to update the checked property. The second problem is that the one-parameter `attr` function is used to read the attribute. You want the two-parameter function to set it.

Here's a working example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[name="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    if ( $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val() === "personalized" ) {
      $('#hidden').prop('checked','checked');
    } else {
      $('#hidden').prop('checked','');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="personalized" value="personalized"/><label for="personalized">personalized</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="general" value="general"/><label for="general">general</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hidden" name="hidden"/><label for="hidden">hidden</label>
```

Comment: i've tried ths, but still not workin - i've updated the question with the html
it should be nide when "personalized" is unchecked, hidden also be unchecked

Comment: @jimi fixed, it just needed an else clause removing the assignment in the `checked` property.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to do it in ready function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if ($(".personalized").is(":checked") ) {
    $('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

if you want them to apply on page load.